# Mango PI- PIC16877A (Not able to display the characters on the LCD)

Tags: c, embedded, pic, lcd, mplab

I am trying to display characters on the LCD using MANGO PI with PIC16F877a
This is my code-

```
#include <pic.h>

__CONFIG(WDTDIS & XT & UNPROTECT);  
char name1[]="KitsNspares";

void delay(int x)
{
    int d,l;

    for(l=0;l<x;l++)
    { 
         for(d=0;d<3000;d++);
    }
}

void instwrt(void)
{
    RC0=0;
    RC1=0;
    RC2=1;
    delay(1);
    RC2=0;
    delay(1);    
}

void datawrt(void)
{
    RC0=1;
    RC1=0;
    RC2=1;
    delay(1);
    RC2=0;
    delay(1);
}

void lcdin(void)
{
    PORTD=0x38;
    instwrt();
    PORTD=0x0E;
    instwrt();
    PORTD=0x01;
    instwrt();
    PORTD=0x06;
    instwrt();
    PORTD=0x80;
    instwrt();
}

void main(void) 
{
    int a;

    TRISD=0x00;
    TRISC=0X00;
    TRISB=0x00;
    lcdin();

    for(a=0;a<11;a++)
    {
        PORTD=name1[a];
        datawrt();
    }

    while(1)
    {
        PORTD=0x18;
        instwrt();
        PORTB=0x0aa;    
        delay(10);
        PORTB=0x55;
        delay(10);
    }
}
```

I used mplabs to code it, and hi-tech universal Compiler to Compile and create the hex file. i haven't gotten any warning to errors, when i upload it on the board, it is successful. But, nothing appears on the LCD. Please Help!!

Comment: In embedded systems, it is extra important that you declare all constant variables `const`. Your variable `name1` will now be in RAM and if you are lucky it gets initialized with a string from flash. In this case, you should just store the actual variable in flash too, by making it `const`. If you picked a non-standard (minimal) start-up code for the project, this is the reason why your program isn't working.

Comment: @Lundin i tried the code by making the variable const. it still isn't working

Comment: Another issue is that your delay loops are nonsense. At best they will give you some random time, at worst they will get optimized away entirely by the compiler. Use hardware timers instead. There has to be a timing spec for the baudrate of the parallel interface. Also, check the lines with an oscilloscope/logic analyser to ensure you get any output at all.